# Google Chrome slowdown after some time

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, freeze

I'm running Google Chrome on Xubuntu 14.04.

After some time, maybe couple of hours or half an hour (I don't on what it depends) it's starting to freeze. It's almost impossible to use it, cause every simple action takes seconds. Page rendering is also very slow. I've tried to run GC without extensions by starting it with `--disable-extensions` CLI argument, but it didn't helped.

Here's the version info:

```
Google Chrome:   38.0.2125.122 (Official Build 290379) 
OS:              Linux 
Blink:           537.36 (@183466)
JavaScript:      V8 3.28.71.19
Flash:           15.0.0.223
User Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36
Command Line:    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path:    /home/sfomin/.config/google-chrome/Default

Variations:

d0bd833b-3f4a17df
f2d919bf-3f4a17df
e9f4800b-2d9ef0cc
76b48ab8-4866ef6e
c70841c8-4866ef6e
9e5c75f1-dba59402
f79cb77b-3d47f4f4
24dca50e-837c4893
ca65a9fe-91ac3782
8d790604-9cb2a91c
4ea303a6-3d47f4f4
d8f57532-3f4a17df
61544484-ca7d8d80
b310ecc7-fcf6c09
9736de91-ca7d8d80
b2612322-f8cf70e2
5a3c10b5-e1cc0f14
244ca1ac-4ad60575
5e29d81-cf4f6ead
3ac60855-486e2a9c
246fb659-4c073154
f296190c-cc017729
4442aae2-d7f6b13c
ed1d377-e1cc0f14
75f0f0a0-6bdfffe7
e2b18481-75cb33fc
e7e71889-4ad60575
cbf0c14e-bf3e6cfd
```

I've tried to completely restart the browser by terminating every process of `google-chrome`, but after I start it again - I'm getting the same freezes. The only solution that helps is to either log out of the system and log back in or to put computer to sleep and wake it up (in this case I can even leave the browser opened).

What could be the reason for this? How do I fix it permanently?

## Update

**lspci -k**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67/P8H67 Series Motherboard
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8469
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation P67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 844d
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570] (rev a1)
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570] (rev a1)
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
05:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
06:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01)
07:02.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 820d
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Which version of Chrome, and do you have [Window compisting enabled in Xfce Window Manager](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KYoIm.png)/Hardware acceleration enabled/disabled in settings? Also, what hardware and drivers are you using (use `lspci -k`).

Comment: Thanks @Wilf for your reply! The version of Chrome is stated in the question which is: `38.0.2125.122 (Official Build 290379)`. Compositing is enabled in XFCE. I've added output of the `lspci -k` to the question.

Comment: The first thing to check is what's happening to memory. What's the output of `top` at the beginning and later when it happens ? (the first 4 lines)